# Automapping inheritance: How to add Discriminator convention for base class

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, automapping

By implementing ISubclassConvention, I can change the Discriminator Value for the subclasses in my class hierarchy. I'm now looking for a way to set the Discriminator Value for my base classes as well. Is there a way to change it with a convention override or do I have to add a manual mapping for my hierarchy?

(The IClassConvention provides the DiscriminatorValue property but it is read-only, so no luck there.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I know is to make simple mapping override just for base class.

```
public class DepotMappingOverride : IAutoMappingOverride<Depot>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Alter the auto mapping for this type
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="mapping">Auto mapping</param>
    public void Override(AutoMapping<Depot> mapping)
    {
        mapping.DiscriminateSubClassesOnColumn("Type", "BaseDepot");
    }
}
```

Now "BaseDepot" will be discriminator value for Depot class.

Comment: Not the answer I was hoping for but I can work with that. Thanks :)